# Запрос из трех стаблиц MySQl

Tags: mysql

Есть три таблицы.

catalog:

```
id | name | 
1  | John |
2  | Petr |
3  | Dave |
```

gods:

```
id | nameId | gods
1  |    2   | Book
2  |    3   | table
```

service:

```
id | nameId  | serv
1  |    1    |  delivery
2  |    3    |  translate
```

пытаюсь сделать выборку

```
SELECT * FROM catalog,gods,service
WHERE gods.nameId=catalog.id and service.id=catalog.id;
```

и, как вы понимаете, получаю только:

```
id | name | nameId | gods | nameId  | serv
3  | Dave |   3    | table|    3    |  translate
```

какой запрос  мне надо  сделать, чтобы получить все данные вот так?

```
id | name |   id   | nameId | gods   |  id    |nameId  | serv
 1 | John |        |        |        |    1   |    1   |  delivery
 2 | Petr |   1    |   2    | book   |        |        |
 3 | Dave |   2    |   3    | table  |    3   |    2   |  translate
```

ну или типа того, но чтобы ячейки выводились все заполненые, несмотря на отсутствие данных.

Comment: Попробуйте руками прописать вывод всех полей вместо символа *

Comment: да это я для примера написал суть же не в том

Comment: @Bo3DuX  или в том ?

Comment: Я предполагал, что в том.
Но в ответах есть идея получше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно воспользоваться директивой `left join`. примерно так (во втором запросе *null*-ы заменены пустыми строками):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e0c/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table c (id int, n text);

create table g (id int, nid int, g text);

create table s (id int, nid int, s text);

insert into c values
   (1, "иван")
  ,(2, "пётр")
  ,(3, "давид")
;

insert into g values
   (1, 2, "книга")
  ,(2, 3, "стол")
;

insert into s values
   (1, 1, "доставка")
  ,(2, 3, "перевод")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from c
left join g
  on g.nid = c.id
left join s
  on s.nid = c.id
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e0c/5/0)**:

```
| id |     n |     id |    nid |      g |     id |    nid |        s |
|----|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|----------|
|  1 |  иван | (null) | (null) | (null) |      1 |      1 | доставка |
|  2 |  пётр |      1 |      2 |  книга | (null) | (null) |   (null) |
|  3 | давид |      2 |      3 |   стол |      2 |      3 |  перевод |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select c.*
  ,coalesce(g.id, ''), coalesce(g.nid, ''), coalesce(g.g, '')
  ,coalesce(s.id, ''), coalesce(s.nid, ''), coalesce(s.s, '')
from c
left join g
  on g.nid = c.id
left join s
  on s.nid = c.id
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e0c/5/1)**:

```
| id |     n | coalesce(g.id, '') | coalesce(g.nid, '') | coalesce(g.g, '') | coalesce(s.id, '') | coalesce(s.nid, '') | coalesce(s.s, '') |
|----|-------|--------------------|---------------------|-------------------|--------------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|  1 |  иван |                    |                     |                   |                  1 |                   1 |          доставка |
|  2 |  пётр |                  1 |                   2 |             книга |                    |                     |                   |
|  3 | давид |                  2 |                   3 |              стол |                  2 |                   3 |           перевод |
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'catalog.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: первый вариант подошел спасибо вам