# Как написать запрос, который будет игнорировать пустые значение

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть запрос, который меня удовлетворяет такого вида

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  persons p 
LEFT JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
LEFT JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id 
WHERE p.id = @id  
LIMIT 1
```

Но есть одно НО! При этом запросе, попадают и пустые поля. Как мне его переписать так, чтобы он игнорировал пустые строки?

При INNER пишет нет записей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно,чтобы запрос возвращал, только заполненные ячейки и если какая-то ячейка будет пустой, то пусть пропускает ее, а невозвращает по ней Null.

Вид моих таблиц такой:

[image: Таблица persons]

[image: Таблица email]

[image: phones]

Comment: Вместо `LEFT JOIN` используйте `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Пустые в основной таблице (persons) или в присоединяемых (phones или emails)?

Comment: Могут быть и там и там

Comment: Попробовал  INNER JOIN теперь он возвращает по пустоту по всем полям

Comment: @shatoidil, т.е. если хотя бы одно пустое поле в любой таблице, то не возвращать данные по запросу? Если нет, то заполняйте данные в таблицах полностью, либо измените условие выборки (не по конкретному id, а шире).

Comment: Мне надо,чтобы он возвращал, только заполненные ячейки и если какая-то ячейка пустая, то пусть пропускает ее

Comment: @shatoidil, показывайте набор данных, как сказал Saidolim Djuraev и результаты при таких-то запросах, какие должен вернуть. Потому что ваше `если какая-то ячейка пустая, то пусть пропускает ее` звучит слишком расплывчато.

Comment: Добавил структуру

Comment: @shatoidil, структура это структура, а данные хранящиеся в базе это другое. Что я, что Saidolim Djuraev просим у вас показать минимальный набор данных, показать запрос применимый к этим данным и показать какой ответ вы ждете в результате выполнения этого запроса. Чтобы-нам, отвечающим, было понятно ваше **если какая-то ячейка пустая, то пусть пропускает ее**

Comment: Это таблица с контактами, то есть данные заполняются исходя из наличия у человека емейла или телефона  и тд. К примеру есть человек Иванов Иван, а отчество вы его не знаете и соответственно ничего в поле middlename не вносите. Поэтому нужно, чтобы запрос смотрел в ячейку и если там ничего нет, то не возвращал мне Null, брал данные только из заполненных ячеек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так не пройдет? :

```sql
WHERE p.id = @id AND p.id != ''
```

Answer (score 1):

для замены *null*-а на что-нибудь другое (например, на пустую строку), можно использовать, к примеру, функцию [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

посмотрите на [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446325/178576), там наглядно показано, как *null*-ы заменяются на пустые строки.

---

одно (возможное) неудобство — вместо `*` в качестве списка столбцов потребуется явно перечислять все нужные столбцы.

---

а ещё можно подмену делать в программе, которая получает данные от `mysqld`.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте просто

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  persons p 
JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id 
WHERE p.id = @id  
LIMIT 1
```

или с `Inner Join`

Comment: При обоих случаях он возвращет пустоту, по всем полям

Comment: покажите пример данных, которые не должны быть пустимы при запросе